# Stream Video from ios device

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

I have integrated FFmpeg libraries to my project.

Now

**i want stream a video that is captured using my ios device (iPhone, iPad, iPod) 
to an RTMP server using FFMpeg.**

I did post a similar question and googled for the same but did not end up with any solution.

**Can anyone of you suggest me a tutorial or atleast direct me as i am badly stuck over here and not able to move ahead.**

Kindly Pour your knowledge.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: you'll probably have to use the libav* libraries [instead of ffmpeg itself] https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav* GL!

Comment: I do have the Libav* (libavcodec,libavdevice,....) and i have also integrates the the librtmp library

Comment: but just dont know how to use it . right now i am trying to use librtmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can check the source code of my streaming app:

https://forum.speeddemosarchive.com/post/kumari_alpha_1.html

Check in common/rtmp_broadcaster.cpp. It is too long to post here. The code should be the same for iOS. You will only have to modify how the captured frame data is input into ffmpeg. Since you already have the frame data, this should not be too difficult.